# How can I add SQL editor by class `SqlScriptEditorControl`

Tags: c#, winforms, editor, ssms

I want to add **Sql**  editor(like `New Query` in SSMS) to form in winForms
How can I do it?
maybe by `SqlScriptEditorControl` class?(full name: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl`)
**How can I use `SqlScriptEditorControl` in order to add Sql  editor?**

Comment: See following webpage : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/tsql

Comment: I'm not sure if you can because that is built for Visual Studio shell integration but it does inherit from Control so you can try it if you have the SqlEditors.dll. Add it from code like any Control - new it up and add it to the form's Control collection. I'd be interested if you get it working.

Comment: It doesn't has ctor but CreateInstanse that requires a parameter: `object serviceProvider` and don't know what to put there

Comment: I don't think it will be practical to try to get it working in a winforms project. There is likely a lot of complex plumbing you would need to wire up.